# How to get system configuration values dynamically in xml file in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, system.xml, system-config

I have created admin grid and form using Ui component, Now I need to get system configuaration values in my form.xml. Please provide me a solution
I need to get width,height,image size from below image.
[image]

**System.xml**

```
<field id="image" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Small Image</label>
                    <frontend_model>X\Y\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config</frontend_model>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>                    
                    <comment>Image size should be in Bytes(1 KB = 1024 Bytes, 10 KB = 10240 Bytes, 50 KB = 51200 Bytes, 100 KB = 102400 Bytes, 150 KB = 153600 Bytes)</comment>
                </field>
```

Comment: maybe you can show some code and give an example of what you need from system config

Comment: See the updated post @Marius

Answer (score 0):

You can use following in your xml:

```
<head {vendor}-config-template="{section}/{group}/{field}">
    <css src="css/rtl.css" />
</head>
```